# What would be the Swift equivalent of General Path of Java?

Tags: java, swift, graphics2d

Currently, I'm writing an iOS app based on a previous implementation which is written in Java. The app is a custom map app and involves drawing a lot. I've been trying to find the class or object that most closely represents General Path of Java. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `General Path of Java` you mean [`java.awt.geom.GeneralPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html)

> The GeneralPath class represents a geometric path constructed from
>   straight lines, and quadratic and cubic (Bézier) curves. It can
>   contain multiple subpaths.

So you should look for [`UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath) in iOS's `UIKit`

> A path that consists of straight and curved line segments that you can
>   render in your custom views.
>
> …
>
> A single Bézier path object can contain any number of open or closed subpaths, where each subpath represents a connected series of path segments.

Comment: Please note that UIBezierPath is from UIKit and is not from the Swift library. UIKit classes and methods are usable in many languages, including Swift.

Comment: @Moritz, `GeneralPath` is also usable in many JVM languages, including Java, i had Swift there to map `of Java` part of question. But fixed anyways.

Comment: Good. I think it's better to be accurate in descriptions. There's already too many beginners who don't understand the difference between Swift/iOS/UIKit/Foundation etc. Thanks.